# Constraints of vector element in FindMinimum

Tags: mathematical-optimization, vector, constraint

I try to find the local minimum of a function $$\Pi(\vec{d})$$
where $$\vec{d} = (d_1,d_2,...,d_n)$$ should satisfy $$d_i>0$$ for $i \in [1,n]$.

I use the `FindMinimum` function in *Mathematica*; *i.e.*, use something like $$\mathtt{FindMinimum}[\{\Pi(\vec{d}),d_i>0\},\vec{d}].$$ But I don't know how to apply the constraints $d_i>0$. If it is indeed possible, it would very much help me to know how to formulate such a command. Thanks!

Comment: `FindMinimum[{pi[dvector], Apply[Min, dvector] > 0}, dvector]` or you can learn to use the various abbreviations that MMA provides and then use `FindMinimum[{pi[dvector], Min@@dvector > 0}, dvector]`

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. Could you please show me where to find the various abbreviations that MMA provides as you said?

Comment: This https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/UseShorthandNotations.html might get you started.

Answer (score 1):

`ConicHullRegion[]` is a useful constraining region to use for vectors with all positive components. In particular, one can express the first orthant for `n`-dimensional space in region form as `ConicHullRegion[{ConstantArray[0, n]}, IdentityMatrix[n]]`.

Using the [generalized Rosenbrock function](https://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/rosen.html) as an example:

```
rosenbrock[v_?VectorQ] := With[{n = Length[v]}, 
  Sum[100 (Indexed[v, k + 1] - Indexed[v, k]^2)^2 + (1 - Indexed[v, k])^2, {k, 1, n - 1}]]

With[{n = 8}, 
     FindMinimum[{rosenbrock[v], 
                  v ∈ ConicHullRegion[{ConstantArray[0, n]}, IdentityMatrix[n]]},
                 {v, ConstantArray[0.5, n]}]]
   {2.46713*^-14, {v -> {1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}}}
```